# I cannot plot this negative graph for some reason on Latex

Tags: pgfplots, luatex

I am trying to plot the equation -\frac{7}{6}\frac{1}{16\pi^2}x^3 but I keep getting the error, missing number treating as zero. I have no idea what is going on because I am a newbie at this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! As long as you do not show us what you have tried one cannot really tell you what went wrong. For me the following works: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=none] {(7/(6*16*pi^2))*x^3};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Yeah I deleted the code out of frustration. But thank you so much and  I hope you get your crystal ball back ;)

Comment: Never use `x^2` or `x^3` in calculations!  `x*x` and `x*x*x` are both faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Since you do not provide us with the code that produced the error, and since [my crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen, I can only guess. There is a chance that you tried to plot the LaTeX code that typesets the function. However, you need to plot the function itself.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} 
\addplot[mark=none] {-(7/(6*16*pi^2))*x^3}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but really sorry for your cristal ball...

Comment: I LOVE YOU SO MUCH! THANK YOUUUUUU

Comment: @marmot Here you will find a new one :) https://www.amazon.co.uk/Domeilleur-Crystal-Decoration-Birthday-Valentine/dp/B07LB2W1BV?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duckduckgo-ffsb-uk-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B07LB2W1BV

Comment: @Sveinung Thanks! But I think these do not work. ;-)